# Time Comparison in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I have an array of times( `HH:mm:ss` ), how to find out which time is bigger of them and which is elapsed? it will be great if i can sort them by ascending.

Comment: "an array of times" - what representation? NSDate?

Comment: Array contains only Time in `hh:mm:ss` format. I have truncated it from the `NSDate`.

Answer (score 1):

If your times are given by strings in the `HH:mm:ss` format, you can convert them to NSDate objects and sort them using a mutable array:

```
NSArray *timeStrings = // however you obtain it...
NSMutableArray *sorted = [NSMutableArray array];
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

for (NSString *dtStr in timeStrings) {
    [sorted addObject:[fmt dateFromString:dtStr]];
}

[sorted sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Now `sorted` will contain the date objects sorted asccending.

Answer (score 0):

```
//COnvert Strings to Dates
//Comparison with current time
NSMutableArray *dates;
for (NSDate *d in dates) {
    if ([d compare:[NSDate date]]== NSOrderedAscending) {
        NSLog(@"Future Time");
    }else if([d compare:[NSDate date]]== NSOrderedSame){
        NSLog(@"Present Time");            
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Past Time");  
    }
}
// For sorting
[dates sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```